# How to configure custom hostname to IP resolutions in my system for web development

Tags: development-environment, hosts

## Preface

A web app can potentially
serve different pages,
depending on the
[hostname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname)
that is requested by the browser,
even if all hostnames are resolved
to the same
[IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address).

### Example

For example, at
`https://app.example.com`,
which resolves to
`1.2.3.4`,
users will find the user interface
and at
`https://admin.example.com`,
which also resolves to
`1.2.3.4`,
awaits a dashboard
through which
only the app's owner can
administrate users and data
in the app.

## What We Need

In short,
we need to enter,
for example,
`http://admin.app:8000/`
in our browsers
and have that `admin.app` resolve to `127.0.0.1`.

## The Question

How can I configure
custom hostname to IP address resolutions
in my development environment?

Answer (score 1):

## (Windows, Linux, OSX) System Wide Hosts File

Simply edit the
[hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)).
Its location
[depends on the OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)#Location_in_the_file_system).
For example:

```
127.0.0.1    app.localhost
127.0.0.1    admin.localhost
```

On Windows you can use
this nifty open source GUI
for editing the hosts file:
[Hosts File Editor](https://hostsfileeditor.codeplex.com/).

### Wildcards

The hosts file does not support wildcards!

### Ubuntu Desktop

Since Ubuntu 12.04,
Ubuntu desktop comes with
a local DNS server,
which might not respect
the hosts file (`/etc/hosts`).
So, for Ubuntu desktop, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31952754/359072)
is best.

Answer (score 1):

## (Ubuntu and Derivatives) Configure NetworkManager's `dnsmasq`

Ubuntu Desktop's default networking configuration is
composed of NetworkManager and its slave `dnsmasq`.

The slave `dnsmasq` listens at `127.0.1.1` and `/etc/resolv.conf` lists it as the only `nameserver`.

This has
[some benefits](https://www.stgraber.org/2012/02/24/dns-in-ubuntu-12-04/).

What it means for this purpose is that we have a fully configurable DNS server, comfortably configured by default.

We can create
`/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/hosts.conf`
and put in it whatever `address` statements we'd like:

```
address=/admin.app/127.0.0.1
```

We can even use wildcards!

```
address=/.app/127.0.0.1
```

See the
[`dnsmasq` documentation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man8/dnsmasq.8.html)
for details
(look for `--address`).

Since `dnsmasq` is started by the `network-manager` service,
then I would assume that the following would restart it
so that new configuration would take effect:

```
$ service network-manager restart
```

But [its init-script does not control slave dnsmasq](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1483882).

Therefore the `dnsmasq` process must be killed and then
the above command would have it start again.

And that is it!

Answer (score 0):

## If Testing In a Virtual Machine

In a virtual machine
`127.0.0.1` and `localhost`
will not reach the host,
but the guest.

In VirtualBox, for example,
by default, the host can be reached
at `10.0.2.2`.
So, the guest VM's hosts file can look like

```
10.0.2.2    host
10.0.2.2    app.host
10.0.2.2    admin.host
```

### Proxy DNS Nameserver Inside a Virtual Machine

If you're setting up
a proxy DNS nameserver
inside a virtual machine
(perhaps for wildcard support in Windows)
the upstream nameserver
is usually provided by the host.
In VirtualBox, it is `10.0.2.3`.

Answer (score 0):

## (Linux) User Specific `HOSTALIASES` File

### Very limited

This would have been my preferred answer
because
it refrains from
altering system configuration.

But:

- It does not support wildcards
- It [does not support hostname to IP address resolution](https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+source/glibc/+bug/1483187)
- It does not support freely configurable subdomains
- It will not work if you have a local DNS server,
  which is the case in modern Ubuntu.

### What is It

It is a [user specific host aliases file](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hostname.7.html).
Notice that the format is not the same as the `hosts` file.

In short, you create a file
which contains host aliases.

For example

```
foo    localhost
bar    localhost
```

and place it at `~/.hosts`.

Then you set an environment variable
`HOSTALIASES`
with the path to the aliases file.
So, for this example

```
$ export HOSTALIASES=~/.hosts
```

Answer (score 0):

## (Windows) Configuring Acrylic DNS Server

[Acrylic DNS Proxy](http://mayakron.altervista.org/wikibase/show.php?id=AcrylicHome) is easy to install and configure.

It can help us get hostnames with aliases quickly in Windows.

And it is open source.

1. Install it.
2. Open the `hosts` file (via the start menu entry).
3. Put in some entries, like `1.2.3.4 >app`.
4. Clear its cache and restart it (via the start menu entry).
5. [Set your DNS server](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-tcp-ip-settings#1TC=windows-7) to `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

(GNU/Linux)

Since all the major distributions are migrating (or already did) to systemd stack the proper place to implement wildcard support would be systemd-resolved: see https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/766 for details.

That would be the place to set custom overrides for DNS as well.

As for windows - its VM should just get DNS from host machine: it's to risky to run it on bare metal anyway.